# A clean way to conceptually extract Parts from a circular list

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language

I quite often run into a situation where I want to treat a list as a circular (repeating) list, and want to take a specific sublist of it, such as...

One past the end of the list:

```
Append[#, First@#] & @ {a, b, c}
```

> {a, b, c, a}

An item preceding the list included:

```
Prepend[#, Last@#] & @ {a, b, c}
```

> {c, a, b, c}

Three rounds of the circular list from the start:

```
Join[#, #, #] & @ {a, b, c}
```

> {a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c}

Or even every second item on the list, for two rounds:

```
Join[#, #][[;; ;; 2]] & @ {a, b, c}
```

> {a, c, b}

Obviously there are more of these where you can combine extended features of `Part` (the `[[` ... `]]` syntax) over circular lists.

What would be the most practical (short, clean, efficient, maybe even elegant) ways to do this, without writing one-off code every time such a small need arises?

Comment: Might consider using expr bags to emulate a linked list. For details see [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6795762)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Perhaps [`ArrayPad`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPad.html):

```
ClearAll[f1]
f1  = ArrayPad[##, #] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
f1[{a, b, c, d}, {0, 1}]
```

> {a, b, c, d, a}

```
f1[{a, b, c, d}, {1, 0}]
```

> {d, a, b, c, d}

```
f1[{a, b, c, d}, {12, 0}]
```

> {a, b, c, d, a, b, c, d, a, b, c, d, a, b, c, d}

Alternatively, you can use `"Periodic"` as the third argument in `ArrayPad`:

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2 = ArrayPad[##, "Periodic"] &
```

**Update:** We can combine `ArrayPad` and `Part`:

```
ClearAll[f0]
f0[a_, b_, c_: All] := ArrayPad[a, b, a][[c]]
```

***Examples:***

```
f0[{a, b, c, d}, {0, 1}](* append first *)
```

> {a, b, c, d, a}

```
f0[{a, b, c, d}, {1, 0}] (* prepend last *)
```

> {d, a, b, c, d}

```
f0[{a, b, c, d}, {1, 1}](*append first and prepend last*)
```

> {d, a, b, c, d, a}

```
f0[{a, b, c, d}, {1, -1}](* rotate right *)
```

> {d, a, b, c}

```
f0[{a, b, c, d}, {-1, 1}] (* rotate left *)
```

> {b, c, d, a}

```
f0[{a, b, c, d}, {0, 8}] (* repeat *)
```

> {a, b, c, d, a, b, c, d, a, b, c, d}

```
f0[{a, b, c, d}, {9, -1}] (* rotate right and repeat *)
```

> {d, a, b, c, d, a, b, c, d, a, b, c}

```
f0[{a, b, c, d}, {-1, 9}] (* rotate left and repeat *)
```

> {b, c, d, a, b, c, d, a, b, c, d, a}

```
f0[{a, b, c, d}, {0, 0}, -1 ;; 1 ;; -1] (* reverse *)
```

> {d, c, b, a}

```
f0[{a, b, c, d}, {0, 8}, ;; ;; 2] (*repeat and take odd parts*)
```

> {a, c, a, c, a, c}

```
f0[{a, b, c, d}, {0, 8}, {1, 3, 4, 7, 9}] (*repeat and take parts 1,3,4,7 and 9*)
```

> {a, c, d, c, a}

Answer (score 18):

It turns out we can do all the required transformations using only `Partition` using the (undocumented) sixth argument to do arbitrary-post-processing:

```
ClearAll[☺]
☺[a_, b_, c_, d_: ;;] := Partition[a, b, b, c, a, ## & @@ {##}[[d]] &];
```

***Examples:***

```
☺[{a, b, c, d}, 5, 1] (* append first*)
```

> {a, b, c, d, a}

```
☺[{a, b, c, d}, 5, 2] (* prepend last*)
```

> {d, a, b, c, d}

```
☺[{a, b, c, d}, 4, 2] (*rotate right *)
```

> {d, a, b, c}

```
☺[{a, b, c, d}, 4, -1] (*rotate left *)
```

> {b, c, d, a}

```
☺[{a, b, c, d}, 4, 1, -1 ;; 1 ;; -1] (* reverse *)
```

> {d, c, b, a}

```
☺[{a, b, c, d}, 12, 1] (* repeat *)
```

> {a, b, c, d, a, b, c, d, a, b, c, d}

```
☺[{a, b, c, d}, 12, 1, ;; ;; 2] (* repeat and take odd parts *)
```

> {a, c, a, c, a, c}

```
☺[{a, b, c, d}, 12, 1, {1, 3, 4, 7, 9}] (* repeat and take parts 1,3,4,7 and 9*)
```

> {a, c, d, c, a}

**NOTE:** `☺` doesn't work in version 12.0.0 (thanks: Christopher Lamb). It works in version 12.3 and in versions prior to 12.0.

**Update:** The same idea used with `Part` as in MannyC's answer:

```
ClearAll[☺☺]
☺☺[a_, b_, c_, d_: All] := a[[Mod[c - 1 + Range[b], Length@a, 1][[d]]]];
```

***Examples:***

```
☺☺[{a, b, c, d}, 5, 1] (* append first *)
```

> {a, b, c, d, a}

```
☺☺[{a, b, c, d}, 5, 4] (* prepend last *)
```

> {d, a, b, c, d}

```
☺☺[{a, b, c, d}, 4, 4](* rotate right *)
```

> {d, a, b, c}

```
☺☺[{a, b, c, d}, 4, 2](* rotate left *)
```

> {b, c, d, a}

```
☺☺[{a, b, c, d}, 4, 1, -1 ;; 1 ;; -1] (* reverse*)
```

> {d, c, b, a}

```
☺☺[{a, b, c, d}, 12, 1] (* repeat *)
```

> {a, b, c, d, a, b, c, d, a, b, c, d}

```
☺☺[{a, b, c, d}, 12, 1, ;; ;; 2] (*repeat and take odd parts*)
```

> {a, c, a, c, a, c}

```
 ☺☺[{a, b, c, d}, 12, 1, {1, 3, 4, 7, 9}] (*repeat and take parts 1,3,4,7 and 9*)
```

> {a, c, d, c, a}

Comment: I really think this solution wins in generality what it loses in elegance!

Comment: @ChristopherLamb, thank you.  Single-smiley works in versions prior to 12.0.0 but it doesn't work in version 12.0.0 (Wolfram Cloud) (yet another reminder not to rely on undocumented "features"). I added a note on version-dependence.

Answer (score 12):

This requires a bit of redundant memory but it also opens the door to vectorization:

```
this = {a, b, c};
next = RotateLeft[this];
prev = RotateRight[this];
```

Now you can do cute things like this:

```
(next - 2 this + prev)/h^2
```

Answer (score 12):

Another possibility is `Partition`

```
Partition[{a, b, c},4,4,1]//Flatten
```

> {a, b, c, a}

```
Partition[{a, b, c},4,5,2]//Flatten
```

> {c, a, b, c}

```
Partition[{a, b, c},9,9,1]//Flatten
```

> {a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c}

Comment: This is quite elegant and short, apart from the need of `Flatten`...

Comment: @kirma `Flatten` should come for free for packed arrays...

Comment: ... but you are probably speaking about elegance.

Answer (score 9):

I would define a `part` function as follows

```
part[list_, n_Integer] := list[[Mod[n, Length@list, 1]]];
part[list_, n__Span]   := With[{nn = {m, Sequence @@ n}}, 
                              Table[list[[Mod[m, Length@list, 1]]], nn]];
```

This version of `part` works exactly like `Part` but uses `Mod` to wrap around. There is an obvious difference: with this definition `part[x,0]` returns the last element of `x` and not his `Head` like `Part` would do.

Let's see some examples. Setting

```
list = {1,2,3,4};
```

we have

```
part[list, 7]
```

> 3

```
part[list, 0 ;; 5]
```

> {4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1}

```
part[list, 2 ;; 11 ;; 3]
```

> {2, 1, 4, 3}

If we want to use an empty `Span` to indicate "until the end" we need to come up with some syntax to tell the function when to stop. So we can add an extra argument for the number of rounds.

```
part[list_, n__Span, rounds_] := part[list, n /. All -> rounds*Length[list]];
```

Which results in

```
part[list,2 ;;, 2]
```

> {2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4}

```
part[list, 0 ;; ;; 3, 3]
```

> {4, 3, 2, 1, 4}

---

For completeness I report here in order the examples of the question

```
part[{a, b, c}, 1 ;; 4]       (*Apppend first*)
part[{a, b, c}, 0 ;;, 1]      (*Prepend last*)
part[{a, b, c}, 1 ;;, 3]      (*Three rounds*)
part[{a, b, c}, 1 ;; ;; 2, 2] (*Every second item two rounds*)
```

> {a, b, c, a}
>   {c, a, b, c}
>   {a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c}
>   {a, c, b}

Answer (score 4):

One convenient solution is to alter the way `Part` works instead of creating a new structure. An easy way to achieve this is as follows:

```
Unprotect[Part];
Part /: Part[List[a_, b__], 1] := a;
Part /: Part[List[a__, b_], -1] := b;
Part /: Part[List[a_, b__], n_?Positive] := With[{m = n - 1}, Part[List[b, a], m]];
Part /: Part[List[a__, b_], n_?Negative] := With[{m = n + 1}, Part[List[b, a], m]];
Protect[Part];
```

With this overloading, `Part` behaves as before *except* it treats the list as circular:

```
{a, b, c}[[4]]
(* a *)
{a, b, c}[[-1]]
(* c *)
```

The zeroth component still refers to the head:

```
{a, b, c}[[0]]
(* List *)
```

We can of course overload other properties of `Part` to achieve greater flexibility:

```
Unprotect[Part];
Part /: Part[List[a__], {b__}] := Table[Part[List[a], c$], {c$, {b}}];
Protect[Part];
```

enables

```
{a,b,c}[[{1,2,3,4}]]
(* {a, b, c, a} *)
```

whereas

```
Unprotect[Part];
Part /: Part[List[a__], Span[min_, max_]] := Table[Part[List[a], b$], {b$, min, max}];
Part /: Part[List[a__], Span[min_, max_, steps_]] := Table[Part[List[a], b$], {b$, min, max, steps}];
Protect[Part];
```

enables

```
{a, b, c}[[1 ;; 10]]
(* {a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c, a} *)
{a, b, c}[[1 ;; 7 ;; 2]]
(* {a, c, b, a} *)
```

which are standard utilities of `Part`, except now all lists are treated as compactified.